# How can I update a figure when button is pressed in a different class in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building a GUI in python using PyQt5. Data is imported using `on_pushButtonLoad_clicked()` and `get_file()` located in `TabWidget`.

My goal is to:

1. transfer this data (importedfile) to `FirstTab()`
2. update the plot `MRChart(importedfile)` using the recently imported data.

I have completed the first goal in transferring the data to `FirstTab()` whereby the plot is generated and can be shown (for demonstrative purposes) in the browser using `fig.show()`. Although `MRChart(importedfile)` is connected to the plotting widget `energy()` by `self.browser`, the figure fails to show in the GUI.

Code:

```
class TabWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

        self.showMaximized()

        #create filter object
        FilterLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        FilterLayout.addWidget(self.createHeader1a(), 2)#column width

        #create tab widget object
        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(FirstTab(self.data), "Tab 1")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(FilterLayout)
        vbox.addWidget(tabwidget)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def createHeader1a(self): # function defining characteristics of each group/grid object
        HeaderBox = QGroupBox("Import Data")

        inputfilebtn = QPushButton("Import")
        inputfilebtn.resize(150, 50)
        inputfilebtn.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        #importrow1
        importrow1layout = QHBoxLayout()
        importrow1layout.addWidget(inputfilebtn)
        importrow1layout.addStretch()

        HeaderLayout = QGridLayout()
        HeaderLayout.addLayout(importrow1layout, 0, 1)
        HeaderBox.setLayout(HeaderLayout)
        HeaderBox.setFlat(True)

        return HeaderBox

    def getfile(self):
        option = QFileDialog.Options()
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',
                                            'c:\\', "CSV files (*.csv)", options=option)

        global importedfile
        importedfile = pd.read_csv(fname[0])

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        self.getfile()
        FT=FirstTab(data=importedfile)
        FT.MRChart(importedfile)

class FirstTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(FirstTab, self).__init__() 
        self.data = data

        # Grid layout of entire tab
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.energy(), 3, 0)
        layout.setRowStretch(3, 3)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)

        self.setLayout(layout)


    def MRChart(self, importedfile): # pie
        fig = go.Pie(labels=importedfile["Label1"], values=importedfile["Label2"])
        layout = go.Layout(autosize=True, legend=dict(orientation="h",xanchor='center', x=0.5))# height = 600, width = 1000,
        fig = go.Figure(data=fig, layout=layout)
        fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0))
        fig.show()# only included to prove that figure has been created
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))


    def energy(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Box Title")

        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        exportfilebtn = QCheckBox("tickbox1")
        middleright = QHBoxLayout()
        middleright.addWidget(self.browser)
        middleright.addWidget(exportfilebtn)
        groupBox.setLayout(middleright)
        groupBox.setFlat(True)

        return groupBox

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabwidget = TabWidget(data=None)
    tabwidget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Updated code in line with musicamante's answer

```
class TabWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.firstTab = FirstTab(self.data)

        #create filter object
        FilterLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        FilterLayout.addWidget(self.createHeader1a(), 2)#column width

        #create tab widget object
        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(self.firstTab "Tab 1")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(FilterLayout)
        vbox.addWidget(tabwidget)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def createHeader1a(self): # function defining characteristics of each group/grid object
        HeaderBox = QGroupBox("Import Data")

        inputfilebtn = QPushButton("Import")
        inputfilebtn.resize(150, 50)
        inputfilebtn.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)

        #importrow1
        importrow1layout = QHBoxLayout()
        importrow1layout.addWidget(inputfilebtn)
        importrow1layout.addStretch()

        HeaderLayout = QGridLayout()
        HeaderLayout.addLayout(importrow1layout, 0, 1)
        HeaderBox.setLayout(HeaderLayout)
        HeaderBox.setFlat(True)

        return HeaderBox

    def getfile(self):
        option = QFileDialog.Options()
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',
                                            'c:\\', "CSV files (*.csv)", options=option)

        return pd.read_csv(fname[0])

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
    importedfile = self.getfile()
    if importedfile is None:
            return
    self.firstTab.MRChart(importedfile)



class FirstTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(FirstTab, self).__init__() 
        self.data = data

        # Grid layout of entire tab
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.energy(), 3, 0)
        layout.setRowStretch(3, 3)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)

        self.setLayout(layout)


    def MRChart(self, importedfile): # pie
        fig = go.Pie(labels=importedfile["Label1"], values=importedfile["Label2"])
        layout = go.Layout(autosize=True, legend=dict(orientation="h",xanchor='center', x=0.5))# height = 600, width = 1000,
        fig = go.Figure(data=fig, layout=layout)
        fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0))
        fig.show()# only included to provde figure is created
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))


    def energy(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Box Title")

        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        exportfilebtn = QCheckBox("tickbox1")
        middleright = QHBoxLayout()
        middleright.addWidget(self.browser)
        middleright.addWidget(exportfilebtn)
        groupBox.setLayout(middleright)
        groupBox.setFlat(True)

        return groupBox

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabwidget = TabWidget(data=None)
    tabwidget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I suppose you're using plotly, right? If that's so, you should have added the related tag, and also specify it either in the post body or in the imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `FirstTab`, instead of using the existing one.

You must keep a reference to the first instance and then call *its* `MRChart` function.

Also, you should *not* use globals: `getfile()` should *return* the value, and you should use that returned value in `on_pushButtonLoad_clicked`.

```
class TabWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data):
        # ...
        self.firstTab = FirstTab(self.data)
        tabwidget.addTab(self.firstTab, "Tab 1")
        # ...

    def getfile(self):
        option = QFileDialog.Options()
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',
                                            'c:\\', "CSV files (*.csv)", options=option)

        if fname:
            return pd.read_csv(fname)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        importedfile = self.getfile()
        if importedfile is None:
            return
        self.firstTab.MRChart(importedfile)
```

<sup>Note that it's good practice to show the window only *after* adding its elements, and it's also usually better to *not* call `show*()` in the `__init__`. It's also pointless to use `resize()` on a widget that is being added to a layout.</sup>

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @musicamante. I have updated the original code, and provided this via an edit to the original question above. Unfortunately, when importing data, the application now crashed with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).

Comment: I figured out that the problem was with "if not importedfile: return". Once removed, it worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: @Philip that if was there for a good reason, but in the bad place, as I forgot that the returned value is from `read_csv`. In any case, you *must* check that a file has been actually selected, otherwise you'll probably get an exception anyway if the user cancels the dialog. See the update.